# 12TB NAS devices at home - need offsite backup solution

Tags: backup, cloud

Me and my wife are both tech-junkies. We have a total of 12TB storage on NAS devices throughout our house. Not all is critical, but some 4TB of it is irreplaceable, family photos, videos from the last 10 years or so, documents and so on.

Currently, we backup the critical stuff onto two local devices, AND we manually take one of those drives in and out of our house for a 'low tech offsite backup solution'.

We'd like to back our critical data to a cloud base, or any other type of offsite backup. Most solutions we researched don't support NAS devices, only local drives (e.g. Carbonite). We're looking for something that would allow us to set up nightly, incremental NAS backup, offsite. We have PC's, Macs and Linux devices that can do the actual backup work off of the NAS. So it's flexible on that.

We'd welcome suggestions. Something with a reasonable price tag (not $400 a month)... would be preferable.

Thank you.

Comment: I think you might need to accept that any service willing to work with 12TB of your data is going to be expensive. That's a LOT of data, definitely not at consumer scale.

Answer (score 2):

An option that could cost a lot of money (I don't know how much) is a server license with Mozy. You would need the server license to backup the Linux drive due to them not having a Linux client. You would backup the Linux hard drive through the Windows or Mac machines.

Another option would be to setup another NAS that is off-site (at work or something) and to use RSync (which is cross platform) to have it backup everything. This one would only require funds to buy the NAS.

Comment: Yeah, with MozyPro, 4TB would cost $2,000 a month. I am not that rich yet ;-)

Comment: LOL! WOW I did not know it would cost that much! wow... Well at least you could use my second suggestion @ronm.

Comment: Putting as NAS device somewhere would require tunneling in there, VPN, security issues, not to mention safety for the device itself. Your point though made me think about colocation. Maybe i can setup a computer to be hosted somewhere, with a public IP address - I can put 2 or more 3TB drives on it and just back up there. The costs should be traffic mostly, but if i do the initial backup at home, and just incremental backups on a daily basis, costs shouldn't be so high - I'll check that option. thanks.

Comment: If you have incremental backups, you will eventually want full backups too. If you don't, it will be a painful process recovering your data. You will have to restore the initial full backup, then you will have to restore every backup up to the point of the last incremental backup. So if in 100 days after your backup, your house floods and the NAS is destroyed, you will spend hours restoring every backup up to the most current incremental backup. You will need larger bandwidth at both the co-location site and you house to complete the task in a reasonable amount of time.